# Sets equality from cardinality of sets and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that two finite sets *A* and *B* are equal if $|A| = |B|$ and $|A∩B| = |A|$?

How would I go about proving it?

Comment: Welcome! Please add context and show what you attempted.

Comment: You only need the first, not the second.  What is your definition of sets being equal?  The first statement is the one I am familiar with, so you don't prove it.

Comment: @RossMillikan Two sets are equal when they have the same elements. The first statement (||=||) would indicate that the two sets are equivalent, not equal.

Answer (score 0):

It is true. Intuitively, it says they overlap on all elements. $|A|=|A∩B|$ means that the set of elements of $A$ that are not in $B$ has cardinality $0$. And vice versa.

This is because $A$ is the disjoint union of $A∩B$ and $A-B$, so $|A|=|A∩B|+|A-B|$

Answer (score 0):

Apply twice the property : if $C \subset D$ and $|C|=|D|<+\infty$, then $C=D$. The first time, to $A \cap B \subset A$, to derive $A = A \cap B$, so $A \subset B$; the second time, to $A \subset B$, to derive $A=B$.